# Django: error in date input field

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I am using django form to render a html form page. Everything seems to working except my datetime form field element. I need to pass the user entered date value to one  MSSQL SP , however , when I am trying to print the entered date it's printing a blank line. I am using  **SelectDateWidget** for my date form field.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here

**forms.py**

```
class ConsistencyForm(forms.Form):

Customer=forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label="Customer Name",
    widget=forms.Select,
    queryset=Customer.objects.all(),
    empty_label=None,
    )

Severity_level=forms.ModelChoiceField(
     label="Severity Level",
    widget=forms.Select,
    queryset=Criticality.objects.all(),
    empty_label=None,
    help_text="</br>"
    )

run_date=forms.DateField(
    label="Run Date", widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(2000, datetime.date.today().year+10)),initial=timezone.now(),
    help_text='</br>')
```

**views.py**

```
def consisreportgen(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ConsistencyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        customername=request.POST.get('Customer','')
        rundate=request.POST.get('run_date','')
        Customer=form.cleaned_data['Customer']
        run_date=form.cleaned_data['run_date']
        print(modules_choosen)
        print(customername)
        print(severity)
        print(rundate)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/consistency/results/')

else:
    form = ConsistencyForm

return render(request,'consistency/consistency.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

If Customer is Model you could not just assign value to it like this

```
Customer=form.cleaned_data['Customer']
```

You should create onject of Customer class and then give him some values, like this:

```
customer = Customer()
customer.name = form.cleaned_data['Customer']
```

Comment: I have one class name "Customer" but here I am using Customer as field name.I guess we can do this.Even if I change the name of form field this doesn't change anything.I am having problem validating my _rundate_ field. I guess I am making myself clear.